# Mongoose Embedded Document, methods "is not a function"

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Is there any reason why the process of pushing an EmbeddedDoc into another Document in Mongoose would strip said document of it's methods?

The script I'm using used to work so I'm not sure what has changed. I know they introduced CoreMongooseArray's at some point in version 5 but I've reverted back to an earlier version of 5.0.7 (which uses normal arrays) and the problem still persists.

I have a Cart schema that embeds Cart Items in an array. The cart item schema has various static and instance methods. These are available perfectly up until the moment I push the document into the Cart document.
At that moment the function are no longer accessible and any attempt to call the results in an error message that the function doesn't exist.

Here are the basic schemas:

CART SCHEMA

```js
let mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;
let idvalidator = require('mongoose-id-validator');
let CartItemSchema = require('./CartItem');
let PromotionSchema = require('./Promotion');
let _ = require('lodash');

let CartSchema = new Schema({

   customer_id: {
     type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   ref: 'User'
   },
   cartItems: [CartItemSchema],
   customItems: [],
   promotionItems: [{type: PromotionSchema, excludeIndexes: true}],
   quantity: {
        type: Number,
        min: 0,
        required: true,
        default: 0
   },
      subtotal: {
         type: Number,
         min: 0,
         required: true,
         default: 0
      },
      subtotalWithoutTax:{
          type: Number,
          min: 0,
          required: true,
          default: 0
      },
   total: {
    type: Number,
  min: 0,
  required: true,
  default: 0
   },
   totalWithoutTax:{
        type: Number,
        min: 0,
        required: true,
        default: 0
   }
 },
    {
     timestamps: true,
  id: false
    }

);

CartSchema.index({ createdAt: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 604800 });

CartSchema.virtual('discount').get(function(){
    return _.round(this.subtotal - this.total, 2);
});

CartSchema.virtual('tax').get(function(){
    return _.round(this.total - this.totalWithoutTax, 2);
});

CartSchema.set('toObject', {virtuals: true});
CartSchema.set('toJSON', {virtuals: true});

CartSchema.plugin(idvalidator);

module.exports = CartSchema;
```

CART ITEM SCHEMA

```js
let mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;
let idvalidator = require('mongoose-id-validator');
let SizeSchema = require('./Size');
let ProductExtraSchema = require('./ProductExtra');

let CartItemSchema = new Schema({
   product_id: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: 'Product',
  required: true
   },
      sku: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
          trim: true,
          lowercase: true
      },
   name: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
  trim: true
   },
   description:  {
  type: String,
  trim: true,
  alias: "desc"
   },
   price: {
    type: Number,
  min: 0,
  required: true,
  default: 0
   },
   priceWithoutTax:{
        type: Number,
        min: 0,
        required: true,
        default: 0
   },
      total: {
          type: Number,
          min: 0,
          required: true,
          default: 0
      },
      totalWithoutTax:{
          type: Number,
          min: 0,
          required: true,
          default: 0
      },
      taxable: {
          type: Boolean,
          required: true,
          default: false
      },
      taxRate: {
          type: Number,
          required: true,
    min: 0,
          default: 0.2
      },
   quantity: {
    type: Number,
  min: 1,
  required: true,
  default: 1
   },
   size: SizeSchema,
      extras: [ProductExtraSchema]
 },
    {
     timestamps: true,
  id: false
    }
);


CartItemSchema.set('toObject', {virtuals: true});
CartItemSchema.set('toJSON', {virtuals: true});

CartItemSchema.plugin(idvalidator);

module.exports = CartItemSchema;
```

These are converted into models in a separate script where the static and instance models are added.

If I then do the following, the methods disappear as soon as the push occurs:

```js
let CartItem = require('../models/CartItem');
let Cart = require('../models/Cart');

let cartItem = CartItem.hydrate(req.body.cartItem);
let cart = new Cart();
console.log(cartItem.calculateTotals);
cart.cartItems.push(cartItem);
console.log(cart.cartItems[0].calculateTotals);

// Console.logs([Function])
// Console.logs(undefined)
```

To make matters worse I created a very basic mocha test, which does essentially the same thing and that succeeds. So, what is the difference?
Why is one succeeding where the other doesn't?

```js
describe('test', function(){

    it('should allow childs methods to be accessed', function(){

        let childSchema = new Schema({

                name: String

            },
            {
                timestamps: true,
                id: false
            }

        );
        childSchema.methods.hyper = function(){
            console.log("I've eaten too many sweets")
        };


        let parentSchema = new Schema({

                name: String,
                children: [childSchema],

            },
            {
                timestamps: true,
                id: false
            }

        );

       

        let parent = mongoose.model('Parent', parentSchema);
        let child = mongoose.model('Child', childSchema);

        let c = child.hydrate({name: 'Sarah'});
        let p = new parent({name: 'Joe'});

        p.children.push(c);

        for(let c of p.children){
            c.hyper(); 
            // Successfully logs "I've eaten too many sweets"
        }

        return true;

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to reproduce this using the following order of schema/model setup:

1. create the `CartItemSchema` schema
2. create the `CartSchema` schema
3. create the `Cart` model
4. add the `calculateTotals` methods to `CartItemSchema`
5. create the `CartItem` model

Step #4 is the culprit: you're modifying a schema that's already being used by a model (indirectly, by `Cart`).

The correct order (or at least, the order that should yield the least amount of issues) should be:

1. create the `CartItemSchema` schema
2. add the `calculateTotals` methods to `CartItemSchema`
3. create the `CartItem` model
4. create the `CartSchema` schema
5. create the `Cart` model

Comment: Thanks for your answer but not sure if this is the case in my instance. By logging the load order I get:

cartItemSchema created
cartSchema created
cartItemSchema added methods
cartItem model created
cartSchema added methods
cart model created

So, the cart model is definitely created last and after the methods are added to CartItemSchema

Comment: Still, the problem points to an incorrect order. Perhaps the schema/model code is being called multiple times? The order that you post in your comment doesn't reproduce the problem in my test code.

Comment: Thanks. Yes it must be being called multiple times or something to do with the cartItem model needing to be declared even before cart schema is. I tried moving the method into the cartItem schema file (rather than it being in a separate model logic file) so I knew it was definitely declared before cart schema and cart model are created and that seemed to work. Still, it doesn't explain why this used to work and all of a sudden stopped?! Thank you for your help though

Comment: All I know is that Mongoose has always been rather picky about the order in which you create schema/models and add statics/methods to them. Perhaps there's been a change where creating the same schema/model multiple times is being handled differently.

Comment: I think you are right. Somewhere along the lines Mongoose has been updated and now doesn't like the order in which things load. It all worked perfectly before so it must have become more picky as you say.